# How to detect YouTube video change in browser in Full screen

Tags: javascript, video, google-chrome-extension, youtube, html5-video

I'm trying to run some javascript (from a chrome extension) every time a new YouTube video loads.
So I have a content script listening to events:

```
// old youtube design
window.addEventListener("spfdone", process);
// new youtube design
window.addEventListener("yt-navigate-start", process);
// one-time early
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", process);
// one-time late postprocessing
window.addEventListener("load", process);
```

But it doesn't work when the video is changed in full screen.
How can I listen for a video change when the Youtube tab is in Fullscreen?

Comment: I have not edited that, but I believe you mean a content script, not a background script?

Comment: @Xan Yes, changed, thanks.

Comment: A complication in your case is that the YouTube HTML5 player in fullscreen will change what's played, but will delay actual navigation/refresh of the page until fullscreen is exited; so even if you do capture the event, your other code (that presumably tries to scrape some info) may not see any updates.

Comment: A bulletproof method seems to be spoofing XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send with your own wrapper that adds `loadend` event listener. You can analyze reponseURL and check DOM. Note, spoofing must be performed in the page context, see [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved it:
repeatedly checking what video the browser is on in the HTML:

```
var link = String(document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-title-link yt-uix-sessionlink")[0])
```